# GTM custom javascript is not working, what to do?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I've created custom js function. It worked on console, however I tried to transfer it to GTM using custom js variable function, it returned undefined. The function transfers a string to integer and removes whitespaces.

```
function(){
  a= parseInt(google_tag_manager["GTM-000000000"].dataLayer.get("gtm.element").querySelectorAll("div>div>div>div")[27].querySelector("div>input").getAttribute("value").replace(/\s/g, ""));
  return a}
```

it returns undefined((

Comment: `parseInt` won't return `undefined` it is either a number or `NaN`. So the shown code wouldn't result in `undefined`. It would either throw an error, or return a number or `NaN`

Comment: @t.niese GTM will return undefined for a custom javascript variable when the code throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

No, the function does a lot more than you indicated. All the dom scraping The reason for it "not firing" in GTM may be due to timing. However, you're not supposed to use this kind of global scope code in GTM.

GTM kindly provides you with a {{Clicked Element}} which you can definitely use in your GTM custom JS code. So your code would become something like:

return {{Clicked Element}}.querySelectorAll("div>div>div>div")[27].querySelector("div>input").getAttribute("value").replace(/\s/g, ""));

Still, you can debug it. You can console.log your google_tag_manager["GTM-000000000"].dataLayer.get("gtm.element") from GTM and then debug it further in your console. The console nowadays allows you to copy a consol logged object, put it in a var and query against it.